# How can I use Joi to sanitize the query parameter for hapi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I was wondering if I can use Joi to automatically sanitize the query parameter instead of manually doing that?

This is what I have done for the route.

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

function dateToString(date) {
  return moment(new Date(querystring.unescape(date))).toISOString();
}

function posts(request, reply) {
  request.query.from = dateToString(request.query.from);
}
```

And this is the Joi schema.

```
var topPostsConfig = {
  description: 'Top posts',
  plugins: {
    'hapi-swagger': {
        order: 1
    }
  },
  validate: {
    query: {
       form: Joi.date().iso().optional().default(moment().subtract(2, 'day').utc().format()).description('start date for query')
    }
  }
}

{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/posts',
  handler: posts,
  config: topPostsConfig
}
```

Just wondering if Joi has any special method to auto sanitize the query parameter to be unescaped characters?

**Edit:**
The request comes in as `2016-02-05T20%3A26%3A34.916Z` which is escaped by the browser. I was thinking if Joi can just unescape that automatically then I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: A little bit more code maybe works to understand what you wants

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: What will happend if you just change the handler for this: `function posts(request, reply) { return reply(request.query): }` what does it print?

Answer (score 1):

First off you have a typo on the field you are validating - "form" instead of "from".

Joi should receive decoded URL query. It's easy to check by replacing JOI query validation object with a function and inspecting the value:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/posts',
  handler: (req, reply) => {
    reply(req.query);
  },
  config: {
    description: 'Top posts',
    validate: {
      query: (value, options, next) => {
        console.log(value);
        next(null, value);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

When you fix the typo in your example it works as expected.

If you want to do some additional data processing you can always just use the function form of validation and using Joi.validate() from the function body.